# How to start a process?

Tags: go

I try to start a JVM out of a Google Go program that looks like this:

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "os"
import "log"
func main() {

var name string
name="\\jrex64\\bin\\java.exe"

var path="-Xbootclasspath:jrex64\\lib\\rt.jar;"+
"jrex64\\lib\\jfxrt.jar;"+
"jrex64\\lib\\resources.jar;"+
"jrex64\\lib\\ext\\sunjce_provider.jar;"+
"jrex64\\lib\\ext\\zipfs.jar;"+
"jrex64\\lib\\ext\\sunmscapi.jar;"+
"jrex64\\lib\\ext\\sunec.jar;"+
"jrex64\\lib\\ext\\dnsns.jar;"+
"jrex64\\lib\\ext\\access-bridge-64.jar;"+
"jrex64\\lib\\security\\local_policy.jar;"+
"jrex64\\lib\\jce.jar;"+
"jrex64\\lib\\jfr.jar;"+
"jrex64\\lib\\jsse.jar;"+
"jrex64\\lib\\charsets.jar;"+
"jrex64\\lib\\";



var args[] string=make([]string,4)
args[0]="-verbose"
args[1]=path;
args[2]="-cp Ganesha_lib\\*"
args[3]="-jar Ganesha.jar"

var attr* os.ProcAttr

proc,err:=os.StartProcess(name,args,attr)
proc.Wait();


if err!=nil {
    fmt.Println("an error occurred.\n")
    log.Fatal(err)
}

}
```

It's my first Go program. And i'm totally overwhelmed by getting the following error:

> panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
>   [signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0x4278b5]
>   goroutine 1 [running]:
>   os.startProcess(0x4aacb4, 0x14, 0xf840001eb0, 0x500000005, 0x0, ...)
>       C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/2/bindist767862039/go/src/pkg/os/exec_posix.go:28 +0x152
>   os.StartProcess(0x4aacb4, 0x14, 0xf840001eb0, 0x500000005, 0x0, ...)
>       C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/2/bindist767862039/go/src/pkg/os/doc.go:24 +0x5c
>   main.main()
>       D:/MyGoProject/src/main.go:60 +0x23c
>   goroutine 2 [syscall]:
>   created by runtime.main
>       C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/2/bindist767862039/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:221
>   Process finished with exit code 2

How do i have to interpret this error code? What went wrong? And how can i get the JVM startet - it's situated in a subdirectory of the Go executable file.

Comment: Try using back ticks (\`) instead of double quotes for your multi line strings. You would not need to escape the back slashes with back ticks. [See this example](http://play.golang.org/p/ReRuedTo0f). Also, there is a package for joining paths in a platform independent manner, see [pkg/path/filepath](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is normally recommended you don't use os.StartProcess directly. Instead, use os/exec which has a much easier interface. Here is how I would start a java subprocess and wait for it to complete.

http://play.golang.org/p/APlp9KK9wx

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var java = "\\jrex64\\bin\\java.exe"

    var path = []string{
        "jrex64\\lib\\rt.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\jfxrt.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\resources.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\ext\\sunjce_provider.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\ext\\zipfs.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\ext\\sunmscapi.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\ext\\sunec.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\ext\\dnsns.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\ext\\access-bridge-64.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\security\\local_policy.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\jce.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\jfr.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\jsse.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\charsets.jar",
        "jrex64\\lib\\",
    }

    pathflag := "-Xbootclasspath:" + strings.Join(path, ";")
    cmd := exec.Command(java, "-verbose", pathflag, "-cp Ganesha_lib\\*", "-jar Ganesha.jar")
    err := cmd.Run()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("an error occurred.\n")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```

In case you are curious, the reason you got that panic was that attr is a nil pointer. Instead, you could have done `attr := new(os.ProcAttr)`.

Comment: Do you need all those \\ marks? Because Windows supports Posix, I think you can use / throughout instead, which is much simpler to read and is portable to other Posix filesystems (notably Linux, Macos)

Answer (score 15):

The previous answers don't actually describe how to use os.StartProcess().  Here's an example:

```
cmdToRun := "/path/to/someCommand"
args := []string{"someCommand", "arg1"}
procAttr := new(os.ProcAttr)
procAttr.Files = []*os.File{os.Stdin, os.Stdout, os.Stderr}
if process, err := os.StartProcess(cmdToRun, args, procAttr); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("ERROR Unable to run %s: %s\n", cmdToRun, err.Error())
} else {
    fmt.Printf("%s running as pid %d\n", cmdToRun, process.Pid)
}
```

Note that it's necessary to initialize the ProcAttr.Files field - if you don't, you may get an index out of bounds error deep in the os package.  You can use pipes for the files if you want to provide input or process output from the new process in your own code.  You may also want to specify the Dir (starting directory) and Env (environment variables) fields.

Comment: The reason is that using os.StartProcess directly is never something you want to do. He didn't ask how to use StartProcess, he asked how to start a process. I answered why his was failing and pointed him towards a better way to implement. I am unsure why he marked your answer as correct.

Comment: @steve You probably should take up this issue with the Go authors.  If using os.StartProcess directly is something you never want to do, then they made a mistake exposing the method.  

In fact, I can't find any support on the web for your statement that startProcess shouldn't be used.  Can you point to a reference?

Comment: From the docs: "StartProcess is a low-level interface. The os/exec package provides higher-level interfaces." Usually this would mean that if you are doing something advanced, it makes sense to use StartProcess. However, everything you can do with start process can be done with os/exec (personal research, easy to verify). StartProcess is there because it is used by os/exec and it fits with kill and wait being there. Those are there because you may want to wait/kill a process you did not launch.

Comment: The doc says it's a low level interface.  It doesn't say not to use it.  IMO, it's pretty uncool to downgrade an answer just because the question's author likes it better than yours.  Just sayin'.

Comment: Meh, should not have downvoted but definitely pointed people away from using StartProcess. You are right about that. Can't undo the downvote unfortunately. Also, looking back at this question, I need to check if it is still relevant. I should probably submit a patch to allow nil for attr.

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
var attr* os.ProcAttr

proc, err := os.StartProcess(name, args, attr)
```

The `attr` variable is nil and when dereferenced in `os.StartProcess` it causes the error you see.

Comment: So would i have to instanciate `ProcAttr`somehow?

Comment: I cannot supply a verified source doing what you want to do (no Java and no Windows here). I suggest to use the `os/exec` package wrapper instead of `os.StartProcess`, it should be easier to use. Here is a generic example: http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Cmd_Start (click on the text "Example".)

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, os.ProcAttr cannot be left empty. At Dir must be set to an empty string and Sys must be set to &syscall.SysProcAttr{}. The following should work:

```
name := "\\jrex64\\bin\\java.exe"
libs := "-Xbootclasspath:jrex64\\lib\\rt.jar;" +
    // add all libs
    "jrex64\\lib\\";
args := []string{"-verbose", libs, "-cp Ganesha_lib\\*", "-jar Ganesha.jar"}
attr := &os.ProcAttr{
    "",
    nil,
    []*os.File{os.Stdin, os.Stdout, os.Stderr},
    &syscall.SysProcAttr{}} //CreationFlags: syscall.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP, } 
}

proc, err := os.StartProcess(name,args,attr);
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("start process: %v", err)
}
_, err = proc.Wait();
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("wait: %v", err)
}
```